# Is it possible to add a collection of strings directly into the Sitecore Content Editor?

Tags: string, collections, sitecore, sitecore7

here's a really quick question...

> Is there a type of Sitecore Editor control that I can use in the Template Builder to enable the product owners to add a free collection of strings in the CMS Editor?

I know that I can add a simple data object that has a single string field, add a number of these data objects and then add a Multilist to the Editor with that group of data objects as the Source, but that would mean that the product owners would have to add all of their strings as these data objects and then select them from the Multilist.

I'm trying to make it simpler for them, but I can't seem to find a Sitecore Editor control that enables them to enter a collection of strings directly in the Editor... is there one?

Comment: Maybe you can use the "Name Value List"  though it is not intended for only a list of string values, but it does qualify and is easy to use

Comment: Thanks Jan, I've looked into the Name value List now... what .NET type does it map to, or is it only used in the query string parameters?

Comment: This works for a Sitecore Name Value List Field: string fieldvalue = item["FieldName"];
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(fieldvalue);

Comment: That won't work in this instance, because I have a collection of objects, with each one having one of these lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no way to do this in Sitecore.

All hope is not lost, however. You can always create your own field type for something like this, but doing so does require a significant level of effort.